# How to place label widgets next to each other?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a simple GUI program to measure time from a certain event. Everything works fine, but there is one thing that bugs me - all the label widgets are "blinking" (due to being created), so I want to restructure my code so that I have two label groups - one of them would be displayed constantly and the other one (actually measuring time) would blink. The problem is when I try to split a label into two smaller labels, I can't get it to be right next to the other one, so it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my original working code:

```
# str8.py
#   Program to count time from a certain event

from tkinter import *
from datetime import *
from threading import *

def display():

    event, today, str8, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years = calc()

    Label(root,
          text = "You have been STR8 for:\n",
          font = "Verdana 8 bold").grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

    Label(root,
          text = "Years: "
               + str(round(years, 2)),
          font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 1, sticky = W)

    Label(root,
          text = "Weeks: "
               + str(round(weeks, 2)),
          font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 2, sticky = W)

    Label(root,
          text = "Days: "
               + str(round(days, 2)),
          font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 3, sticky = W)

    Label(root,
          text = "Hours: "
               + str(round(hours, 2)),
          font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 4, sticky = W)

    Label(root,
          text = "Minutes: "
               + str(round(minutes, 2)),
          font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 5, sticky = W)

    Label(root,
          text = "Seconds: "
               + str(round(str8.total_seconds())),
          font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 6, sticky = W)

    Button(root,
           text = "EXIT",
           font = "Verdana 8",
           height = 1,
           width = 19,
           command = quit).grid(row = 7)


def calc():

    event = datetime(2017, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0)
    today = datetime.now()

    str8 = today - event

    seconds = str8.total_seconds()
    minutes = str8.total_seconds() / 60
    hours = minutes / 60
    days = hours / 24
    weeks = days / 7
    years = weeks / 52

    return event, today, str8, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years


def print_it():
    t = Timer(1.0, print_it)
    calc()
    try:
        display()
    except RuntimeError:
        pass
    else:
        t.start()

def quit():
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("STR8")
    root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    print_it()
    root.mainloop()
```

...before I tried to split one of them for a try by:

```
Label(root,
      text = "Years: ",
      font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 1, sticky = W)

Label(root,
      text = str(round(years, 2)),
      font = "Verdana 8").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
```

I would then put all the labels that are being displayed constantly into create_widgets() function, and leave the others in the display() function.

I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: you're redrawing every widget every time you update - this really isn't necessary

Comment: Could you suggest me an alternative solution, I'm still a newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TKinter has a [variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) called `DoubleVar`, which lets you create a variable that you can use to update a Label widget. Using this method, rather than using `text=` for the label, you use `textvariable=` to refer to the variable you have created and Tk knows to update the label when the variable changes value (though it should be noted that there are alternative ways to achieve an updating label, which I won't detail here).

In the following code, we create two text labels per time unit - one to tell the user what the value relates to, and another to actually show the value. I've done this via a dictionary for simplicity.

We then call `increment` for the first time, which sets all of the relevant values. After doing this we use `self.after(1000, self.increment)` to run the increment process after 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

```
# str8.py
#   Program to count time from a certain event

from tkinter import *
from datetime import *


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid(sticky=N + W + E + S)

        Label(self, text='You have been STR8 for:', font="Verdana 8 bold").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

        self.counters = dict()
        measurements = ['Seconds', 'Minutes', 'Hours', 'Days', 'Weeks', 'Years']
        for i, measurement in enumerate(measurements):
            self.counters[measurement] = DoubleVar()
            Label(self, text=measurement, font='Verdana 8').grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky=W)
            Label(self, textvariable=self.counters[measurement], font='Verdana 8').grid(row=i + 1, column=1, sticky=E)
            self.counters[measurement].set(0)

        Button(self,
               text="EXIT",
               font="Verdana 8",
               height=1,
               width=19,
               command=quit).grid(row=7, column=0)

        self.increment()

    def increment(self):
        event = datetime(2017, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0)
        today = datetime.now()

        str8 = today - event
        self.counters['Seconds'].set(round(str8.total_seconds(), 2))
        self.counters['Minutes'].set(round(str8.total_seconds()/60, 2))
        self.counters['Hours'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / 3600, 2))
        self.counters['Days'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / (3600 * 24), 2))
        self.counters['Weeks'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / (3600 * 24 * 7), 2))
        self.counters['Years'].set(round(str8.total_seconds() / (3600 * 24 * 7 * 52), 2))

        self.after(1000, self.increment)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.title("STR8")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

This results in a window that looks like the following:

[image]

and should update every second without flashing.

Comment: Are you aware that you don't need to use `DoubleVar` (or any of the other tkinter variables) in order to update a label? Your answer seems to imply it's the only way.

Comment: @BryanOakley through `.config`?

Comment: @BryanOakley reworded to try make it clearer that this isn't the only way - just happened to be the one I thought of. Would there be any reason excluding preference to use another method?

Comment: I prefer not to use the variables simply because it adds extra objects to my code that have to be managed. Updating a label requires a function call with or without the variable, so why add the overhead of the variable?

Comment: @asongtoruin I appreciate your help when it comes to updating every second without flashing, but now I have other problems with my GUI. I want the labels to be next to each other, or one label, for instance, Years: 0.0

Comment: @wraith46 either switch the columns round (numbers on the left, descriptions on the right) or switch the `sticky` settings so the descriptions are `sticky=E` and values `sticky=W` rather than the other way round?

Comment: @BryanOakley fair enough - I find it easier to understand by using variables, particularly if those values are to be used in a subsequent process.

Comment: @asongtoruin No, I just want my window to look as it did before. Now there is a huge gap between two labels. Except that, everything is fine.

Comment: @wraith46 try setting the `text` labels to have `column=1` and the `textvariable` to have `column=0`